# Ubuntu 13.04: dummy output after reboot

Tags: sound, 13.04, output

I have got problem with audio (Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller as lspci says) on my laptop hp probook 4530s with Ubuntu 13.04 and kernel 3.8.0-19.

Sometimes it stops working (not during work, before loging), reboot usually helps but it is annoying and next time again there won't be sound. Audio settings shows only "dummy output". 
Dmesg says interesting thing:
http://pastebin.com/vUfq7xpP

Had anyone similar problem?

Comment: I have a `Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)` and I have been using 64bit 13.04 since it was in beta, I have had no sound issues on it, i have not checked HDMI audio thought, you may want to try reinstalling `pulseaudio` or using a [mainline kernel](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater#readme)

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: +Jorge could you give the bug ID? Otherwise how's this a "known" bug?

Comment: Check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/294016/no-sound-in-ubuntu-13-04-only-dummy-output-device-listed/299915

Comment: Thank you. But why my question was closed? -.- and that one isn't?