# Audio not working in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: nvidia, sound

I have a unique problem. My os is ubuntu14.10 and in my sound settings "play through" is blank with not even dummy output.I have NVIDIA graphics card.

On running this command sudo aplay -l,

```
I got the following output
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

“play output through” is empty in my sound settings and the output volume is
unchangeable. I reinstalled alsa and pulsesudio but did not get any results. Please help me.
```

Answer (score 0):

What usually works for me is to `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

After that restart your system. Sorry if this doesn't work or if you have tried this before.

Also is it a recent install?

Comment: I have already tried this. But this did not work. Yes it is a recent install

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I have anymore ideas. But this might help?

http://askubuntu.com/questions/294016/no-sound-in-ubuntu-13-04-only-dummy-output-device-listed