# No sound on 16.04 and only audio device is "dummy output"

Tags: sound, kernel, dell, pulseaudio, alsa

Yesterday I bought a new Dell laptop (inspiron ) and had everything working fine, installed somethings and turned it off. Today I worked with it by the morning (and listened some music) and by the afternoon I had to restart it and when it started over it had no sound on the speakers or headphones. The sounds configuration only shows "Dummy output" on the output tab. I seached a lot for some help and could find some steps like:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1316634 and [No sound in Ubuntu 13.04, only Dummy output device listed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294016/no-sound-in-ubuntu-13-04-only-dummy-output-device-listed) and I tried everything I could find and nothing works. No help from Dell's official tech support. Does anyone had a similar problem on 16.04 and solved it?

Comment: Do a real shutdown  . Try to disable fastboot in bios. run  "aplay -l "   in  terminal  and see if a sound device is there.

Comment: @laugeo -  My fastboot has three options: Minimal - Reduces time by skiping hardware and configuration initialization during boot. Thorough - Performs complete hardware and configuration initialization during boot. Auto - Allows the BIOS to decide confiration initialization performed during boot. Thorough is checked by default. How to disable it?

Comment: aplay -l returs `aplay: device_list:268: no soundcard detected...`

Comment: fastboot is ok but i would test using   ubuntu 17.04