# no sound on ubuntu 16.04.In setting it says dummy sound

Tags: sound

no sound on ubuntu 16.04 .In setting it say dummy sound after downloading on to a mini pc it says dummy sound what does that mean .what can i try ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persistent Dummy Output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800262/persistent-dummy-output) and [No sound in Ubuntu 13.04, only Dummy output device listed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294016/)

Answer (score 1):

Try `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem a couple hours ago. Usually just switching to a different device fixes it but not this time. So I used:

```
rm ~/.pulse/           # In my case this directory was empty
rm ~/.config/pulse/*
pulseaudio -k
```

There was a link I followed: https://askubuntu.com/a/15226/307523